# How to find a solution for this inequation?

Tags: inequality, roots

what's the best way to find a solution for the following inequation:

$$
\sqrt{x^2-1}>x
$$

The result is as Wolfram says:

$$
x \leq-1
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing to note is that you *mustn't* directly square the terms.

1. In order that the inequality makes sense, you need $x^2-1\ge0$
2. Recall that $\sqrt{a}\ge0$ (when $a\ge0$) by definition, so an inequality $\sqrt{a}>b$ where $b<0$ is automatically true as soon as $a\ge0$.
3. If $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$, the inequality $a>b$ is equivalent to $a^2>b^2$.

So you have two cases to deal with.

### Case 1

\begin{cases}
x^2-1\ge0\\
x<0
\end{cases}
which is equivalent to $x\le-1$

### Case 2

\begin{cases}
x^2-1\ge0\\
x\ge0\\
(\sqrt{x^2-1})^2>x^2
\end{cases}
that has no solution, because the last inequality becomes $-1>0$, which is false.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: @SuzuHirose OP asks for the "best way", which arguably isn't the most foolproof way.

Comment: @user2345215 I don't like your answer because it doesn't clarify what logic to use to solve this kind of (slightly ridiculous) problem. egreg's answer is much better since it is careful about each step in the logic. So this is the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For this to even make sense, $x$ must be in $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$. If it's in $[1,\infty)$, then
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}>x\iff x^2-1>x^2,$$
which is impossible. If, on the other hand, $x$ is in $(-\infty,-1]$, it's trivially true as the left side can't be negative.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is not the fastest but aims to explain how to select cases for $x$.

Firstly exclude the cases that $-1<x<1$ because in that case the term $x^2-1$ inside the square root would be negative, since $$x^2-1<0 \iff x^2<1 \overset{\sqrt{\cdot}}\iff |x|<1 \iff -1<x<1$$ Now, select cases

- Let $x\ge 1$. Then you can divide both sides with $x$ without changing the direction of the inequality sign and you obtain $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}>1 \iff \sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}}>1\iff \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}>1$$ But the root of the number is greater than $1$ if (and only if) the number is greater than $1$ so the last equation reduces to $$1-\frac{1}{x^2}>1 \iff -\frac{1}{x^2}>0$$ which is however impossible since $x^2>0$ (in particular for $x>1$ as we have assumed in this case).
- Let $x\le -1$. Then you can divide both sides with $x$ but now you have to change the direction of the inequality sign (since you divide with a negative number) and thus you obtain $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}<1 \iff \sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}}<1\iff \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}<1$$ But the root of the number is less than $1$ if (and only if) the number is less than $1$ so the last equation reduces to $$1-\frac{1}{x^2}<1 \iff -\frac{1}{x^2}<0$$ which is always true since $x^2>0$ and therefore $$-x^2<0 \iff -\frac{1}{x^2}<0$$ So the inequality is true always under this cases, therefore the inequality holds for every $$x\le-1$$ and there are no other solutions as we saw with the previous cases.